# Definition of curl

Tags: vector-fields

Curl(F)=$\nabla\times F$

I am finding it difficult to understand why cross product gives Curl. Is this like torque equation $\tau=R\times F$? What is the direction of $\vec{\nabla}$?

In case of a scalar field $F=F(x,y)$, $\nabla F$ gives a vector in the $x-y$ plane which points along the direction of maximum increase of $F$.

Comment: You can take it as a definition, or you can look into a physics or physics oriented multivariable calculus book to get an intuitive idea of what it represents for a three dimensional vector field.

Comment: I was using DJ Griffiths book. So is $\nabla \cdot F$ also simply a definition for divergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a symbolic notation. You can always think of $\nabla$ as the "vector"
$$\nabla = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ,  \frac{\partial}{\partial y},  \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right).$$

Well this is not a vector, but this notation helps you remember the formula. For example, the gradient of a function $f$ is a vector 
$$\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} ,  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y},  \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right),$$
which you get think of it as 
$$\nabla f =  \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ,  \frac{\partial}{\partial y},  \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) f$$
(Like multiplying $f$ to the vector $\nabla$). The divergence of $F = (A, B, C)$ is given by 
$$ \text{div} F = \frac{\partial A}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial z},$$
which can also be written as 
$$ \nabla \cdot F = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ,  \frac{\partial}{\partial y},  \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) \cdot (A, B, C).$$

On the other hand, the Curl can also be given by 
$$\begin{split} \nabla \times F &= \left|\begin{matrix} i & j & k \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ A & B& C \end{matrix} \right|\\
& = \left|\begin{matrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\  B& C  \end{matrix}\right| i - \left|\begin{matrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ A& C  \end{matrix}\right| j + \left|\begin{matrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\  A& B  \end{matrix}\right| k \\
&=\left( \frac{\partial C}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial B}{\partial z}\right) i -\left( \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial A}{\partial z}\right)  j + \left( \frac{\partial B}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\right)  k
\end{split}$$

In my opinion, this just give you a way to remember the formulas.

Comment: Why do you obtain Curl on taking the determinant? I understood the $\vec{\nabla}$ part.

Comment: In general the cross product of two vector is $a\times b = \left| \begin{matrix} i & j & k \\ a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \end{matrix} \right|$. @AdityaDev

Comment: I know that. Just one thing. Does $\nabla\times F$ have some geometrical meaning like torque.

Comment: I understood divergence after reading Feynman lectures. It's just the Curl.

Comment: I am not sure if there is an analogy between torque and curl. @AdityaDev